# Shareplum Office365 connection spontaneously broke

Tags: python, sharepoint

I had been using the following code daily for the past month or so to pull a SP list and connect to another data source

`from shareplum import Site`

`from shareplum import Office365`

`import pandas as pd`

`authcookie = Office365('https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com', username='SharePointAdmin@COMPANY.com', password='ADMINPW').GetCookies()`

`. . .`

However it seems to have spontaneously broken and am now getting the error:

`Exception: Check username/password and rootsite`

I don't have enough Python or sharepoint knowledge to understand whose end this error is on. Seems to be an authentication issue but it was working fine and our SP guy says nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below parameter when you connect to Office 365:

```
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
site = Site('https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/sbdev',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
```

Here is a demo you can take a reference: 
[downloadfile.py](https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/PythonConsole-uploadfileSPO/PythonApplication2/downloadfile.py)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a language problem. Our filesystem is in german, so I changed from

'Shared Documents' to 'Freigegebene Dokumente'

and everything works fine.